# Collecting lists using Reap/Sow

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I have a list like `{{a,x},{b,y},{c,x},{d,z},{e,y}}` and would like to produce from it a list formed by collecting all top-level elements whose second components are the same into a single list. For the list above, the desired output would be `{ {{a,c},x}, {{b,e},y}, {d, z}}`. Here `x`, `y`, and `z` could also be lists, if that matters. This seems like an application of `Reap` and `Sow`. But the on-line documentation of these functions is pretty poor, and the examples don't add much. Shifrin's [book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/) keeps referring to a discussion of Reap and Sow in Part II, but I can't actually find a part II. Is there a resource somewhere that I can look at to understand the ins and outs of these functions, and see some real examples of how to use them?

The simple `Reap[Map[Sow[#, #[[2]]] &, r]]`, where `r` is the list above, produces almost what I want, but instead of `{{a,c},x}` above, it produces `{{a,x},{c,x}}`.

(I'm sure that someone will post a solution to my programming problem; for that I would be grateful. But I really would like to understand these functions better.)

EDIT: The code `Reap[Map[Sow[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, r], _, {#2, #1} &] // Rest` does the trick. Perhaps there's a better way. In any case, my question about documentation still stands.

Comment: Probably `GatherBy` is the way to go here.  What in the docs is unclear/missing in your opinion? There are several answers using `Reap`/`Sow` around,  a search may be useful.

Comment: @YvesKlett My major whine was that there seemed to be no way to see exactly what `Sow` was doing, but looking at more examples, I realized that providing an undefined function name as the third argument of `Reap` will show me exactly what my `Sow` produced. I'm much happier now. And `GatherBy` with a little postprocessing worked as well, so now I have two possible solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question may be deemed a duplicate, as the specific operation has been addressed before (actually quite a few times as I recall).  Nevertheless I shall attempt to provide a useful answer regarding `Sow` and `Reap`.  First, I there are many examples of the use of these functions on this site, and I encourage you to search for them, as they will provide a broader application than is practical in a single answer.

For your given example you could write:

```
data = {{a, x}, {b, y}, {c, x}, {d, z}, {e, y}};

Reap[Sow @@@ data, _, {#2, #} &][[2]]
```

> ```
> {{{a, c}, x}, {{b, e}, y}, {{d}, z}}
> ```

This doesn't *quite* match your desired output but it is a more consistent format.

However, you mention:  "Here `x`, `y`, and `z` could also be lists, if that matters."  Yes, it does matter, because if the second argument of `Sow` is a list it is not treated as a single tag but a list of tags.  Therefore you need to wrap the list itself in `{}` to have it treated as a single tag.  First an example of the failure:

```
x = {1, 2, 3};

Reap[Sow @@@ data, _, {#2, #} &][[2]]
```

> ```
> {{{a, c}, 1}, {{a, c}, 2}, {{a, c}, 3}, {{b, e}, y}, {{d}, z}}
> ```

And then the correction:

```
Reap[Sow[#, {#2}] & @@@ data, _, {#2, #} &][[2]]
```

> ```
> {{{a, c}, {1, 2, 3}}, {{b, e}, y}, {{d}, z}}
> ```

---

A few posts you should read:

- [Can someone explain this code for joining two lists by the first element of each sublist?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31076/121)
- [Defining Tags in Reap](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6415/121)

Perhaps also of interest:

- [combining and comparing lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36905/121)
- [Gather list elements by labels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28606/121)

---

Version 10 update: although specifically `Reap` and `Sow` were requested I think it is worth noting that this can be done with Associations as well, e.g.:

```
{#2, #} & @@@ Normal @ GroupBy[data, Last -> First]
```

> ```
> {{{a, c}, x}, {{b, e}, y}, {{d}, z}}
> ```